# Getting "LC_ALL: cannot change locale" error. What's wrong?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

When I open any kind of terminal I get this error

```
bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US)
```

My `/etc/default/keyboard` contains

```
XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="dk"
XKBVARIANT=""
XKBOPTIONS="terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp"
```

and `/var/lib/locales/supported.d/local` contains

```
en_GB.UTF-8 UTF-8
en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8
```

In `dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` selected I

```
Generic 105-key (Intl) PC
Denmark
Denmark
The default for the keyboard layout
No compose key
Yes
```

**Question**

What I would like is to have Danish keyboard layout, and everything else (menus and such) should be English.

Can anyone figure out why I get this error and perhaps how to correct it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Locale doesn't really have much to do with keyboard layout.

The error message is a result of setting your locale to en_US, presumably either in /etc/default/locale or one of your shell startup files, but it looks like you've only asked the system to provide en_GB.UTF-8 and en_US.UTF-8.

On a modern system both UTF-8 locales are good choices, so the answer is figure out where you've specified en_US and replace it with en_US.UTF-8 or en_GB.UTF-8, according to taste.